CodeBlocks с LLVM Clang. Как нормально и адекватно настроить?
Захотел я на C++ писать. Скачал clang+llvm-19.1.0 с https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html. Скачал CodeBlocks, т.к. не понял как в VS подключить компилятор под C++, а не под Visual C++. Помогите настроить компилятор. Вот файлы в bin:


нужно поставить флаги.



2)нужно выбрать файлы

3) и вот...


"не понял как в VS подключить компилятор под C++, а не под Visual C++" - Вот про это поподробнее. Что значит "не под visual c++"? Майкрософт называют свой компилятор "visual c++", но это просто маркетинговое словечко, по сути - тот же С++. Какие у вас были проблемы с VS?

@HolyBlackCat Как мне известно так называемый "Visual C++" подходит больше для Windows и на нём работают MSVC и Clang-cl. Мне просто захотелось иметь так же возможность разрабатывать  программы под Linux.

Тогда да. "linker for dynamic libs" = clang++.exe, "linker for static libs" - видимо llvm-ar.exe (у вас такой есть в поставке?), "debugger" = LLDB, "resource compiler" = windres.exe, "make program"=mingw32-make.exe` (по образцу вот отсюда, только переделал под кланг).

Но я бы советовал лучше взять VSCode.
